# Specialization traits of nested struct

Tags: c++11, templates, template-specialization, type-traits, template-argument-deduction

I have a template struct with a nested template struct.

```
template <int F>
struct foo
{
    template <int B>
    struct bar {
        static constexpr int f = F;
        static constexpr int b = B;
    };
 };
```

I want to create a trait like

```
template <class>
struct is_foo_bar : std::false_type { };

template <int F, int B>
struct is_foo_bar< foo<F>::bar<B> > : std::true_type { };

static_assert(is_foo_bar< foo<1>::bar<2> >::value);
```

This gives an error:

```
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class> struct is_foo_bar’<br>
struct is_foo_bar<foo<F>::bar<B>> : std::true_type { };
```

If I take  `bar` out like

```
template <int F, int B>
struct foo_bar {
    static constexpr int f = F;
    static constexpr int b = B;
};

template <int F>
struct foo
{
    template <int B>
    using bar = foo_bar<F, B>;
};

template <class>
struct is_foo_bar : std::false_type { };

template <int F, int B>
struct is_foo_bar< foo_bar<F, B> > : std::true_type { };

static_assert(is_foo_bar< foo<1>::bar<2> >::value);
```

... it works. But this is not the way I want it to be. What I'm missing in code where `bar` declaration is in `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SFINAE it could be solved this way

```
template <class, class = void>
struct is_foo_bar : std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct is_foo_bar< 
    T,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v< T, typename foo<T::f>::template bar<T::b> >
    >
> : std::true_type { };
```

This works, but you need to specify all arguments explicitly, which may be a problem (for ex. variadic arguments).

**EDIT**: Found a soultion for variadic arguments

```
template <int F>
struct foo
{
    template <int B, class... Params>
    struct bar {
        static constexpr int f = F;
        static constexpr int b = B;
        static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Params);
    };
};

template <class, class = void>
struct is_foo_bar : std::false_type { };

template <template <int, class...> class T, int B, class... Params>
struct is_foo_bar<
    T<B, Params...>,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<
            T<B, Params...>,
            typename foo< T<B, Params...>::f >::template bar<B, Params...>
        >
    >
> : std::true_type { };

template <int, class...>
struct not_foo_bar {
    static constexpr int f = 0;
};

static_assert(is_foo_bar< foo<1>::bar<2> >::value);
static_assert(is_foo_bar< foo<1>::bar<2, int> >::value);

static_assert(not is_foo_bar< not_foo_bar<1> >::value);
static_assert(not is_foo_bar< not_foo_bar<1, int> >::value);
```

This makes sure `bar` belongs to `foo`. When there is no such requirement it should be less ugly to just test for existence of needed members with `std::void_t` and `std::declval`...

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm missing in code where `bar` declaration is in `foo`?

You have forgotten a `typename` and a `template` in writing the partial specialization

```
template <int F, int B>
struct is_foo_bar< typename foo<F>::template bar<B> > : std::true_type { };
// not deducible  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  deducible context
```

but the real problem is that the first `int` template value, `F`, is before the `::` so is not deducible.

You can define this partial specialization but is never used.

Comment: @VladimirTalybin - well... maybe if you explicit the first integer value... otherwise I don't see a way.

Comment: Ok, thank you @max66. Will wait a while for other suggestions before marking the answer. I was also thinking to test to specialize with SFINAE. Will try it later...